# Alt+V starts the default text editor. Why?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, nano, gnu

I've searched everywhere, in the ubuntu 20.04 default shortcuts, and among the terminal shortcuts. Yet I can't find why this key is assigned to nano. How can I disable it? And first of all, who, when and why assigned that combo to that piece of software?

I've removed nano, and the shortcut is still active, but with another default editor (like mc or something):
Removing nano (4.8-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/mcedit to provide /usr/bin/editor (editor) in auto mode
Processing triggers for install-info (6.7.0.dfsg.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...

Comment: `Alt+V` does nothing in my vanilla 20.04.2 installation.

Comment: Can't reproduce that either. Is it a global shortcut working from within any window? Check your shortcut settings.

Comment: I have no idea where this has been set. If I create a new profile, that should be "vanilla", or are there global root shortcuts? @vanadium

Comment: @24601 That's incredible, did you try it in the terminal? thanks

Comment: Yes, just now - it does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that this only happens in bash and in vi mode:

```
$ set -o vi
$ <alt-v> starts nano
$ set -o emacs  # the default
$ <alt-v> nothing happens
```

I have experimented a little and it seems that what alt-v is actually doing is prompting for a series of commands to execute. For example:

1. `alt-v` -> nano opens
2. write two lines `echo 123` and `echo abc`
3. `ctrl-x`
4. type y when prompted to save the file
5. type ENTER to confirm the filename (bash-fc.XXXXXX)

Result:

```
echo abc
abc
echo 123
123
```

Unfortunately I have searched A LOT and haven't found a way to change or remove this behavior. I have looked into readline and bind documentation.Also changing the FCEDIT environment variable or creating a .inputrc file to no avail.
Any more info would be appreciated.

Reference:

https://linux.die.net/man/3/readline

https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins

https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Use_vi_shortcuts_in_terminal

Comment: Ah, incredible skills :-) what would you do now? Would it be necessary to open a bug in bash?

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is with 'vanilla' bash as bind (a bash built in command) doesn't report the key. I'm guessing it's probably the Ubuntu package that introduced this "feature" but until I see the source code line I can't be sure.